# Calculate difference with preceding value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have data in a format similar to that set out in the table below:

[image: Example]

I need to calculate (in Column B) the difference between the number in Column A (where there is one) and the first number that appears above that number - also in Column A.

For the example set out above:

B2-B4 would contain `#N/A` and B5 would contain `-1` (as 9-10 = -1).

B6-B8 would contain `#N/A` and B9 would contain `-1` (as 8-9 = -1).

etc.

I tried, in this example, to use a series of `IF` functions like this:

```
=IF(A5=NA(),"",A5-(IF(A4=NA(),IF(A3=NA(),IF(A2=NA(),IF(A1=NA(),"",A1),A2),A3),A4)))
```

But it didn't work (as I think it is pretty much nonesense) and my actual data set can have large gaps between values in Column A.

I know I could filter out `#N/A` in Column A and run a simple calculation - but I was hoping to have a formula that works for the whole column as the data may change.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-Array Solution:

Insert a column between Column A and Column B to track the most recent numeric value, using this equation, starting in cell B2:

```
=IF(ISERROR(A2),B1,A2)
```

Drag that formula to the bottom of your data set.

In the next column, insert this formula, starting in cell C2:

```
=IF(COUNT($A$2:A2)<2,"",IF(ISERROR(A2),"",A2-B1))
```

Drag this formula down to the bottom of your data set.

You'll now have the numeric difference (-1) showing anytime there's a numeric value in column A, and a blank cell anytime there's an error value in column A.

Comment: The new column in this formula doesn't track the number as you suggest - `ISERR()` excludes `#N/A`

Comment: @Gavin121 change the `ISERR` to `ISERROR` and it will work.

Comment: Good catch - post edited to reflect the correct error catching statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Array formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(A2),NA(),A2-INDEX(A:A,MATCH(2,IF(ISNUMBER($A$1:A1),1))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting Edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Put in B2, Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter, then drag/fill down.

[image]